# Infinite loop (C)

Tags: c, warnings, declaration, implicit-declaration

The problem this this code is in the while loop under beetleSimulation, it goes on forever instead of exiting when x/yCount goes out of the bounds. x and y go on much further than 20, can anyone help me out to why?

```
      #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <math.h>
        #define PI 3.14159265
        void beetleSimulation(int, int)

;


    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
        if ( argc != 2 ) // argc should be 2 for correct execution 
        {
            // If the number of arguments is not 2
            printf("%d", argc);
        }
        else 
        {
           //run the bee
```

tle simulation
            beetleSimulation(argv[1], argv[2] );
            }
        }

```
void beetleSimulation(int size, int iterations){
    int i;
    int xCount = 0;
    int yCount = 0;
    int timeCount = 0;
    int overallCount = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
        while(xCount < 20 || xCount > -20 || yCount <20 || yCount >-20){
            timeCount += 1;
            int degree = rand() % 360;
            double radian = degree / 180 * PI;
            xCount += sin(radian);
            yCount += cos(radian);
        }

        //when beetle has died, add time it took to overall count, then go through for loop again
        overallCount += timeCount;
    }
    //calculate average time
    double averageTime = overallCount/iterations;
    printf("%d",averageTime);
}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `beetleSimulation`?

Comment: And where are the types of `size` and `iterations` for that matter? This code is incomplete.

Comment: You have to include `<stdlib.h>` for `rand()`.

Comment: When you have compilation errors, it usually helps to include them in the question. Include them verbatim, except that if the file name being compiled contains slashes, show only the basename of the file - but leave other pathnames unchanged. It is easier to diagnose problems. Please do not invalidate answers with edits to the question. You have many errors in the remaining code.  You should add newlines to the end of the print for the number of arguments; you should exit too when the arguments are wrong.  You need to convert the argument strings into integers before calling your simulation.

Comment: You might also care to note that the result of `sin()` and `cos()` is between -1 and +1, and the chances of getting exactly -1 or +1 is slim to nil, so the additions like `xCount += sin(radian)` are going to be adding 0 to `xCount` almost all the time, which doesn't change the value by much.  Maybe you need to make `xCount` and `yCount` into `double`?

Comment: I did to that! But now its stuck in an infinite loop for some reason. For some reason, the xCount and yCount keep going way past the 20 where it should stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to declare beetleSimulation
- Your variables have no types in the beetleSimulation Definition
- Your printf statements are just wrong. You need to use %d and wrap it in quotations.
- main has no return
- Your also declaring variables within your logic, you need to do that at the top of the function (ANSI)
- In your main, 2 arguments is argv[0] and argv[1], so a.out NUMBER

Your beetlesimulation function requires 2 inputs, so you need 3 arguments.

- You're redefining variables in your while loop, that makes utterly no sense at all.

http://pastebin.com/RuuVDJdp

Here's a compiling version of your code, however it runs an infinite loop it seems, but it compiles.

Comment: Top of the function? Do you mean with the #includes?

Comment: He has type definitions within the logic of the function, such as in the while loop and at the end of the function. They should arguably, be at the start of the function with the other definitions, especially the ones in the loop.

Comment: "Your also declaring variables within your logic, you need to do that at the top of the function (ANSI)" -- Mixing declarations and statements has been valid since C99. Why advise the OP to follow the old standard? (There are sometimes reasons to do so, but no indication that it's necessary in this case.)

Comment: It's valid, but not needed. Like you can write code validly without indentation, that doesn't mean it's good practice. Mixing declarations is useful sometimes, but in this instance (the end of the while with the double) is unneeded, and (in the while loop) was actually in err, as it he would redefine the variables every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop due to code using `||` but needs `&&`.
`xCount < 20 || xCount > -20` is always true

```
// while(xCount < 20 || xCount > -20 || yCount <20 || yCount >-20){
while(xCount < 20 && xCount > -20 && yCount <20 && yCount >-20){
```